# Find IP Address of Cisco 2811

Tags: cisco, switch, router, dhcp, voip

I'm trying to configure the phone configuration on my business' Cisco 2811 router. Without buying a bunch of dongles and connecting through the console port of the router, I'd like to try to SSH or Telnet into the router. **My problem is that I don't know the IP of the Cisco 2811 router.** The topology goes something like this.

```
DSL -> DSL Motorola Modem -> Cisco 2950 Switch -> Cisco 2811 Router -> Phones                                           
                                               -> Workstations
```

I'm pretty sure that the modem is acting as a DHCP server and being a pretty dumb modem it doesn't offer a DHCP table to show which devices are getting which IP's.

What I basically need to do is backtrack through a workstation, to the switch, to somehow get the IP of the switch and SSH/Telnet into the switch to find out which IP the router is getting. Once I have the IP of the router I can try SSH/Telnetting into the router and be able to configure it that way.

Someone please correct me if I'm wrong but would this be a way to go about this?

Comment: Are the phones using the 2811 as their entire phone system (CUCME), or do they talk back to a centralized CUCM at another site?

Comment: I'm about 90% sure that they use the 2811 as their phone system.

Comment: Thanks for the response, second question:  If you do get the IP address of the 2811, do you know the login credentials?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can get them from the individual who set it up. If I can't, I thought there was a way to recover it without wiping the whole router config, correct?

Comment: Yes, you can recover the system, but that requires the "bunch of dongles" you don't want to buy for console access. (it's a standard RS-232 serial port. it comes from cisco with the necessary cable; or get one for $5 on eBay)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your 2811 is providing the phone services for your Cisco IP Phones at this site, finding the IP Address of the 2811 is relatively easy:

1. Press the "settings" button on one of the phones
2. Choose "Device Configuration"
3. Choose "Unifed CM Configuration"
4. Choose "Unified CM 1" or whichever says "Active"
5. The listed IP address is the IP address of whatever device is controlling the phones (either the 2811 on site, or a CUCM at another facility)

The specific steps may vary depending on your phone models and firmware versions, but this should guide you in the right direction.

---

With all of that said, it really sounds like (based on your previous question and this one) that you're taking some stabs in the dark.   I ***HIGHLY*** recommend checking out Jeremy Ciora's book from Cisco Press: "[CCNA Voice 640-461 Official Cert Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1587204177)".  It will help guide you through many of the questions you might have about Cisco IP telephony, and IP telephony in general.   I've given it to several folks over the years, and it has helped them greatly.

Comment: You seem to be well on your way to earning the nickname Mr VoIP :)

Comment: @MikePennington This VoIP stuff is like a plague; now that I've touched it at work, I can't get rid of it.  And no one will let me touch anything else.  I miss routing and switching!  :)

Comment: Seriously I meant that in the best possible way, but I understand... I have the same problem with wifi at work

Comment: I got the IP of the default gateway off of the IP phones of 10.10.10.1. The network of the ip phones and the network of the workstations must be on different vlans configured on the switch. I can't ping the 10.10.10.1 router from any of the workstations. I purchased, on ebay, a cisco console rollover cable which I also will need to buy the dongle for.

Answer (score 3):

`Traceroute` seems like your easiest option. Point it to something outside of your network (like google).  Using that will resolve any device along the path.

> root@xxx:~# traceroute -n google.com
>   traceroute to google.com (173.194.37.100), 8 hops max, 60 byte packets
>   1  x.x.228.1  0.429 ms  0.495 ms  0.615 ms
>   2  x.x.214.57  1.392 ms  1.997 ms  2.717 ms
>   3  x.x.6.53  15.051 ms  15.432 ms  16.069 ms
>   4  x.x.77.253  19.433 ms  20.015 ms  20.553 ms
>   5  109.159.254.132  17.706 ms  18.263 ms  18.615 ms
>   6  195.99.126.109  20.793 ms  21.157 ms  21.433 ms
>   7  209.85.252.186  20.599 ms *  20.774 ms
>   8  209.85.253.94  21.257 ms  16.791 ms 209.85.244.240  17.158 ms
>
> root@xxx:~#

In the instance above, the router would likely be x.x.214.57.

Comment: I thought of this but the only devices connected to the 2811 router are the phones. There are no available ethernet jacks/cards on the router for plugging in a laptop or PC.

Comment: @gh0st I think I misunderstood your setup.  Just traceroute to one of the phones.  You can get one of their IPs, right?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'll give this a try tomorrow morning.

Comment: Or go to one of the phones and see what it's gateway is???

Comment: That would work too I just didn't think the phones had this kind of capability. Haven't worked in the realm of voip before. :/

Comment: @gh0st Your phones **absolutely** have that kind of capability; the only question is whether you have the permissions to obtain that information, or not.  Most organizations lock down their phones so you can't even change the ring-tone.  Reason being: VoIP phones reveal a **lot** of information about the switch on the other end (i.e. LLDP information) since they have to register on the VoIP VLAN and pass both tagged and untagged traffic.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use CDP to get IP address of directly connected device, for e.q from 2950 switch or workstation by sniffer. Sw2950> sh cdp nei * detail.